# Solve $-(x+1)y' - (x+1)y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I must solve the ode: $$-(x+1)y' - (x+1)y = 0$$
where $y=y(x)$. However, because I have two non-constant coefficients I do not know the method needed to solve this. Can someone please tell me the method needed?

Comment: Are you sure ? $(x+1)$ and $(x+1)$

Comment: Even if the coefficients were different, the equation would still be separable.

Comment: You all are correct. I am very sorry for not understanding this before posting the question. 

Thank you all for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide both sides by $-(x+1)$ in order to get
\begin{align*}
y' + y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow e^{x}y' + e^{x}y = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{x}y)' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{x}y = c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = ce^{-x}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Note that the equation is trivially satisfied for $x = -1$, so we don't need to worry about division by $0$.

Comment: I thought we couldn't divide by $-(x+1)$ because what we do not the value of $x$. So it could be that $x+1 = 0$

Comment: @JoshuaWang Thanks for the enriching comment.

Comment: The subtlety here is that while we can easily check $y\propto e^{-x}$ either side of $x=-1$, that the same multiple of $e^{-x}$ is used on both sides follows from $y^\prime(1)$ being well-defined, so $y$ is differentiable, hence continuous, at $x=1$.